# How can I order by grouped and ordered multiple columns?

Tags: sql

I want to return the count of bookings of the top 10 (most) booked destinations per weekday (how many customers booked to those top 10 destinations on Monday, Tuesday etc.).

I wrote this query, but I cannot order properly.

```
select  Destination, DATENAME(WEEKDAY,BookingDate) as Day, count (DATENAME(WEEKDAY,BookingDate)) as Booking
from Booking
GROUP BY Destination, DATENAME(WEEKDAY,BookingDate)
ORDER BY Destination,count(Destination)  desc
```

It should be like this.

```
Destination   | Day |        Booking
Portugal     Monday          5
Portugal     Tuesday         4
Portugal     Wednesday       1
Spain        Monday          3
Spain        Tuesday         2
Spain        Monday          3
```

Comment: your SQL seems give what you want, what is the problem actually?

Comment: Maybe second order by should be `count (DATENAME(WEEKDAY,BookingDate)) desc` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is a good start. I think that this is what you want.
See the DBfiddle link at the bottom to test further.

> ```
> SELECT  
>   DAYNAME(BookingDate) AS Day, 
>   Destination,
>   COUNT(BookingDate) AS Bookings
> FROM Booking
> GROUP BY 
>   DayName(BookingDate),
>   DayOfWeek(BookingDate),
>   Destination
> ORDER BY 
>   dayofweek(bookingdate),
>   Destination
> ```

> ```
> Day       | Destination | Bookings
> :-------- | :---------- | -------:
> Sunday    | Portugal    |        1
> Monday    | Portugal    |        1
> Wednesday | Portugal    |        1
> Wednesday | Spain       |        4
> Saturday  | Portugal    |        4
> Saturday  | Spain       |        3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e86d072f48a2ea25924a2c1ca411081d)*